# Nested lists in python containing a single string and not single letters

Tags: python, list

I need to load text from a file which contains several lines, each line contains letters separated by coma, into a 2-dimensional list. When I run this, I get a 2 dimensional list, but the nested lists contain single strings instead of separated values, and I can not iterate over them. how do I solve this?

```
def read_matrix_file(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as matrix_letters:
        for line in matrix_letters:
            line = line.split()
            matrix.append(line)
    return matrix
```

result:

```
[['a,p,p,l,e'], ['a,g,o,d,o'], ['n,n,e,r,t'], ['g,a,T,A,C'], ['m,i,c,s,r'], ['P,o,P,o,P']]
```

I need each letter in the nested lists to be a single string so I can use them.

thanks in advance

Comment: So you need `'a,p,p,l,e'` to be `'apple'` or `'a','p','p','l','e'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` function splits on white space by default. You can fix this by passing the string you want to split on. In this case, that would be a comma. The code below should work.

```
def read_matrix_file(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as matrix_letters:
        for line in matrix_letters:
            line = line.split(',')
            matrix.append(line)
    return matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

The input format you described conforms to CSV format. Python has [a library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) just for reading CSV files. If you just want to get the job done, you can use this library to do the work for you. Here's an example:

Input(test.csv):

```
a,string,here
more,strings,here
```

Code:

```
>>> import csv
>>> lines = []
>>> with open('test.csv') as file:
...     reader = csv.reader(file)
...     for row in reader:
...             lines.append(row)
...
>>>
```

Output:

```
>>> lines
[['a', 'string', 'here'], ['more', 'strings', 'here']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the strip() function will get rid of the new line character as well:

```
def read_matrix_file(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as matrix_letters:
        for line in matrix_letters:
            line = line.split(',')
            line[-1] = line[-1].strip()
            matrix.append(line)
    return matrix
```